# utf-8 problem with rawurldecode and browser address bar issue

Tags: php, utf-8, urldecode

I have some problems with rawurldecode with Turkish character set.

I have a turkish word (yeşil means green) which needs to be passed as GET parameter.

Here is my generated link.

```
search.php?renk=ye%C5%9Fil
```

When I clicked this link browser address bar shows it like that. (It is decoded properly)

```
search.php?renk=yeşil
```

And the problem starts from here. When I modify url in browser address bar (like adding extra get parameter) and hit enter browser modifies keyword and it generates url like below.

```
search.php?renk=ye%FEil
```

After this point server side code doesn't handle parameter and generates wrong results. Is there any standard way of avoiding this?

Thanks.

Comment: you should avoid non-english characters in the address bar because of that. Every extra decoding and coding characters may result in a bad string. Remember that most of the users have their browsers in english.

Comment: @Mihai Iorga : And what if we're talking about website, which is made primarily for Turkish-speaking users, without a single english word in the interface? I doubt many of that website users will have unlocalized browsers.

Comment: How do you modify the URL? What you see in the adressbar is a representation generated by the browser, the request will still use the encoded URL. (Don't care about the used characters, you of course can use any if they are encoded)

Comment: @Nameless my opinion is english for everything that is not related to user. As I cannot read russian/bulgarian .. etc URL's they all should be english, I make my websites with english parameters, my code comments are in english and I'm Romanian...

Comment: @Mihai Iorga I do so myself, code, urls, etc - all in english. And I'm Russian. I've just responded to "Remember that most of the users have their browsers in english". That's not true for country-specific websites.

Comment: @Mihai Iorga: It's not required that you can read(understand) an url. The characters may com from a form sended via GET, how would you avoid the use of those characters? I'm happy that google still allows me to search for "Käsespätzle" or "Motörhead"

Comment: It it just my opinion and what I recommend. For example I once had to do something on an russian website, i couldn't do anything because Google Translate didn't exist on that time and GET parameters were in russian. From that day forward i made everything in english. just my 2¢ :)

Comment: @Mihai Iorga: The GET-parameter is well encoded here(thats the requirement, nothing else), it's a browser-feature when they are shown unencoded, so you don't need to worry about the website-developer. He doesn't have control about the representaion inside the adressbar

Comment: hi guys, thank you for good comments. The real deal is I want to use turkish characters because my search engine makes pattern matching. It requires exact keyword to match strings properly. Because of this I couldnt make transliteration in urls, because it is impossible to make reverse transliteration on server side. Firefox and other browsers are capable of to show decoded parameters. It is really meaningful for user. Because encoded string isnt readable. But while user tries to enter non-ascii characters it isnt encoded as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your browser converts link to iso-8859-9 encoding, or something similar.
%FE is urlencoded ş from iso-8859-9 encoding.

I've tried `iconv("iso8859-9", "utf-8", rawurldecode("search.php?renk=ye%FEil"))` and it worked.

Comment: Good catch.  That's pretty nasty, that it decodes to something other than Unicode. It should be re-encoding to UTF-8 in any event, not to ISO-8859-9.

Comment: it is really good catch. but how I can determine when it has to be applied. Because if user click a link it works, but if he enters same string to address bar decoding has to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Urls are always using US-Ascii !

See RFC: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

> No corresponding graphic US-ASCII:
>
> URLs are written only with the graphic printable characters of the 
>   US-ASCII coded character set. The octets 80-FF hexadecimal are not
>   used in US-ASCII, and the octets 00-1F and 7F hexadecimal represent
>   control characters; these must be encoded.

now you are running into lots of problems.
if you paste a url into the browser, the url field sometimes relies on OS locales.
the browser may convert it.
sometimes firewalls and proxys may filter urls!

the next important question is:
how does the web server interpret those high chars.
how does it transfer it to php (depending on gateway). php decodes urls automatically, what will happen there with you high chars? php doesn't take care about encoding.

in my opinion the is only one solution to be save.
encode your unicodestring into a base64encoded string.
this will be save within the url - because it is ascii.

within your script you can decode it and you have it back in your encoding you set before.

Comment: It is true, but this rfc is published 17 years ago which is very long time in terms of technology. BTW, there is also encoding techniques which doesnt break those rules. The problem is while rawurlencode uses utf-8 character set, browser could choose to use iso-8859-9 for encoding non-ascii chars. php is ok for utf-8 character set. all parameters converted as expected. In my opinion use base64 is not very good practice in terms of user experience. Web application has to be clear as urls sharing is best way to share information.

Comment: Firstly, that RFC is outdated. It was superceded by [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), and then [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) and the [IRI specification](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/Overview.en.php). Secondly, all modern browsers are already capable of encoding non-ASCII characters, and PHP is fully capable of processing non-ASCII strings. IRIs are no exception. Lastly, how would a binary-to-text encoding help? Browsers already percent-encode non-ASCII characters. The problem here is keeping track of the original character encoding.

Comment: If you Base64 encode the original data, you still need to decode it before you can do anything useful with it. So what then? You've just turned the text data back into binary data. How does that help you determine what the original encoding was?

Comment: You have no control what proxy’s or firewall do with those special chars. there is no encoding specified. Some will transfer ascii, other utf8 and other iso-8859. in lack of encoding information’s, he can specify in his case what is encoded in the base64. But he can’t, specify how the proxy/firewalls/webserver handles non ascii. base64 is ascii and safe for conversions by those systems.

Comment: When you are reading that rfc3986 on page 14/15 there’s still defined: URI must be ascii - other chars have to be encoded! yes, they are talking to use utf-8 and percent (url) encoding. Anyway when you are looking at his samples - he has an encoding problem between webpage, server and browser. Reason he want to enter text in his Turkish encoding and not the required UTF-8 with URL encoding.